# Problems with ActionBarDrawerToggle menu icon afer refreshing appcompat_v7

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat, android-actionbar-compat

After refreshing appcompat_v7 i've needed to delete stroke with menu icon.
And I am having back image in this place now!

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
        //  R.drawable.menu, // i was had to delete it
            R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open  
            R.string.app_name // nav drawer close 
    )
```

So how can I add menu icon now? Thnx

Comment: can you place an image what it looks like.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6vkk8r8ra1kxyi0/Screenshot_2015-04-11-22-11-44.png?dl=0

Comment: and active menu: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6vkk8r8ra1kxyi0/Screenshot_2015-04-11-22-11-44.png?dl=0

Comment: you mean the overflow button with 3 dots you want to remove?

Comment: no, I want to remove back button icon and set menu icon at that place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've added

```
getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

in each fragment. Menu was shoown, but color was grey.

I changed grey color to white by adding one stroke in my styles.xml

```
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
```